# Is this how a mobile website should be called?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I'm trying to create a very basic mobile website as a test. I've been thinking about how people might go about doing this. I assume that one would use a JavaScript function onload of the webpage which decides which css file is used. For example

```
if ( window.navigate.platform === "iPhone" ) {
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" link="mobile.css">
}
else {
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" link="desktop.css">
}
```

Is this the correct general idea, or is it done differently?

Apologies for my limited knowledge - I know it's a rather basic question

Comment: What does Google says?

Comment: "Responsive Design" and "CSS Media Queries" will get you started. Generally, don't "sniff" for specific platforms or browsers, but rather create your site to function at each different "category" of size/device (phone, tablet, desktop). You can either create entirely separate style sheets, or use media queries within a single style sheet - there are pros & cons to either approach.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this but a lot modern websites use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) to do this. Bootstrap will do things like rearrange a page on a mobile device but you can even specify different layouts for different devices without having to have different css files.

Have a look into the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). It might not be what you need for a "simple" website but building your website on it might be easier if you are looking at using it for both sets of devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can target different screen sizes in your `link` tags using media queries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

using media query like this, u can change the class style each screen width

```
  @media (max-width:1024px) {
   .body{color:red;}
    }

    @media (max-width:762px) {
    .body{color:blue;}
    }  ​

    @media (max-width:640px) {
   .body{color:orenge;}
    }
    @media (max-width:480px) {
    .body{color:orenge;}
    }
    .body{color:orenge;}
    @media (max-width:414px) {
    .body{color:orenge;}
    }
    @media (max-width:375px) {

    }
```